# Always show the baseline in amCharts chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

After many issues I finally was able to complete my web-application, however, one last problem remains with my chart (rendered using amCharts lib).

Sometimes there is only one entry in my dataset and when this entry is negative the chart automatically adjusts the "viewing area" to be within the entries range, e.g. the entry's value is -20, then the chart shows everything between -19 and -21.

What I want to achieve is to always show the baseline / zeroline / whatever it might be called and a value slightly above it (e.g. +5).

Using the same example as above, the chart would show values from + 5 to - 25 or something, instead of just showing -19 to -21.

I tried consulting amCharts documentation but couldn't find any properties or events that adress this.

Does anyone know a property which achieves this by any chance or has an idea for a workaround?

best regards,

daZza

Comment: @zeroin Maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "valueAxes" settings you can add the [minimum](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minimum) and maximum values to display.

```
"valueAxes":
[{
    "id": "m3",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Units",
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 100
}]
```

I have added an example on jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5jk5jceq/) for you demonstrating the minimum and maximum values for you.